# How can I add a row which includes a button column to jquery datatable with json

Tags: jquery, datatables

this is the datatable definition

```
table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data: GetData4Grid(requino,0),
    columns: [
        {
            className: 'details-control',
            orderable: false,
            data: null,
            defaultContent: (requino != 0) ? '<button class="gridbtn">Select</button><br /><button class="gridbtnR">Remove</button>' : '',
        },
        { title: "Key" },
        { title: "Priority" },
        { title: "Part" },
        { title: "Description" },
        { title: "Quantity" },
        { title: "Unit_Cost" },
        { title: "Ext_Cost" },
        { title: "Vendor" },
        { title: "Status" },
        { title: "Due_Date" },
        { title: "Current_Approver" },
        { title: "Account" }
    ]
});
```

if I load the grid from the very beginning it work's fine... but once initialized   and if I add a new row the buttons don't show up

[image]

[image]

Comment: show us code , how you are adding row to `Datatable` ?